# how to get rid of pop up xcodebuild pop up on my MAC when I open android studio?

Tags: android, xcode, flutter

I am using Android studio and doing flutter project on it, and when I open my my android studio, I start getting pop up that Xcode is trying to install apple software, and even on cancelling it it pop back again.What is that for? And I am not even doing or running any project on Xcode. How to avoid that and get rid off from that.[image]

Answer (score 1):

xcodebuild is required for the iOS part of your flutter project.

Comment: so it means I have to update it, right? and I thought that some hacker is trying to get in my MAC.

Comment: yeah, go ahead.

Comment: @GAGANSINGHI felt the same lol